# GraphQL-Ruby : When executing a mutation, get error Variable $...... is declared by ....(mutation).... but not used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

I'm cutting my teeth on GraphQL ruby here and this seems like it should be basic but the docs make this very difficult to grok. Where did I go wrong here?

My goal is simply to make a GraphQL mutation in my Ruby app.

**app/graphql/types/mutation_type.rb**

```
module Types
  class MutationType < Types::BaseObject

    field :name, String

    field :create_trip, mutation: Mutations::CreateTrip
  end
end
```

Here's the mutation in
**app/graphql/mutations/create_trip.rb**

```
class Mutations::CreateTrip < Mutations::BaseMutation
  null true
  argument :leavingFrom, String

  field :name, String

  type Types::TripType

  def resolve(leavingFrom: )
    new_trip = Trip.create(leavingFrom: leavingFrom)

    # this doesn't really do anything--- this is proof-of-concept code only
    if new_trip.save
      # Successful creation, return the created object with no errors
      {
        trip: trip,
        errors: [],
      }
    else
      # Failed save, return the errors to the client
      {
        trip: nil,
        errors: trip.errors.full_messages
      }
    end
  end
end
```

the **app/graphql/types/trip_type.rb** is

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Types
  class TripType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :traveling_party_id, Integer
    field :name, String
  end
end
```

When I run this mutation:

```
mutation CreateTrip($leavingFrom: String) {
  name
}
```

(with some data for leavingFrom)

**I get this unexpected result: "Variable $leavingFrom is declared by CreateTrip but not used"**

Expected result: My mutation calls through to the resolve on my GraphQL mutation.

I think the problem is in my query, because it does not look like the Ruby code ever called. Contrary to the message itself, the **[image: Ruby variable]** leavingFrom is indeed used by the mutation in the resolve body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71096321/18196512) is totally right.

On a more explanatory way, when you are executing a query or a mutation (operation type), you can name your operation or not.

```
<operation_type> <operation_name(optional)> (<variables>) {
  # your query or mutation
}

# without naming it
mutation($input: String) {
  # your mutation
}

# naming it 
mutation MyMutation($input: String) {
  # your mutation
}
```

Also I personally always use camelCase to name my mutations/queries and have a different name between mutation/query and operation name, using your example, I would do something like this:

```
mutation CreateTripMutation($leavingFrom: String) {
  createTrip(leavingFrom: $leavingFrom) {
    name
  },
}
```

Hope to have helped you

Comment: Thank you! I think my issue is the Ruby-GraphQL docs, which don't show the difference between the inner & outer clearly. I will go with this as my starting point and get it working. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
mutation CreateTrip($leavingFrom: String) {
  CreateTrip(leavingFrom: $leavingFrom) {
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: so.... `CreateTrip` is used twice in the mutation, but declared only once in GraphQL-Ruby? I think what has tripped me up, pun intended, is that the GrpahQL example have separate (distinct) names for the mutation and the thing on the inside that gets called